# Terminology for different types of Qualcomm DSPs

Tags: android, kernel, signal-processing, qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

What is the difference between aDSP and cDSP. I've seen these terms be overloaded quite a bit.

In the Qualcomm DSP user guide it says:

"The processing units include a Kryo CPU, an Adreno 640, and four separate DSPs, each devoted to a specific application space: sensor (sDSP), modem (mDSP), audio (aDSP), and compute (cDSP)."

However, [other sources](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~danav/pubs/qcom/hexagon_micro2014_v6.pdf) use the acronym aDSP for "application DSP".

When I check through the adsprpc driver which DSP is being used, I only see communication through the Linux file `/dev/cdsprpc-smd` (although I only see `/dev/adsprpc-smd` when not running any application)

Is there a definitive source for the differences between these?